# if else and counter are not doing what is expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

For some reason my counter isn't changing to 1 when I click again it makes the width 100% again.(Found this out using Chrome's inspect)

```
$(document).ready(function columnreacts1() {
    var columncounter1 = 0;
    if (columncounter1 == 0) {
        $("#lol").click(function() {
            $("#column1").animate({ width: '100%' });
        });
        $("#lol").click(function() {
            $("#column2").hide();
        });
        columncounter1 = 1;
    } else {
        $("#lol").click(function() {
            $("#column1").animate({ width: '50%' });
        });
        $("#lol").click(function() {
            $("#column2").show();
        });
        columncounter1 = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why should it change? You're not changing it in one of your four click handlers for `#lol`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the condition need to be checked after click event. Inside the event check the `if` condition.Also action on `column2` & `column1` is due to same event,so attaching one click event will work

```
$(document).ready(function columnreacts1() {
    var columncounter1 = 0;

    $("#lol").click(function() {
        if(columncounter1 === 0) {
            $("#column1").animate({width: '100%'});
            $("#column2").hide();
            columncounter1 = 1;
        }
        else {
            $("#column1").animate({width: '50%'});
            $("#column2").show();
            columncounter1 = 0;
        }
    });
});
```